# How to implement something like std::copy_if but apply a function before inserting into a different container

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

Full disclosure, this may be a hammer and nail situation trying to use STL algorithms when none are needed. I have seen a reappearing pattern in some C++14 code I am working with. We have a container that we iterate through, and if the current element matches some condition, then we copy one of the elements fields to another container.

The pattern is something like:

```
 for (auto it = std::begin(foo); it!=std::end(foo); ++it){
    auto x = it->Some_member;
    // Note, the check usually uses the field would add to the new container. 
    if(f(x) && g(x)){ 
      bar.emplace_back(x);
    }
  }
```

The idea is almost an accumulate where the function being applied does not always return a value. I can only think of a solutions that either

- Require a function for accessing the member your want to accumulate and another function for checking the condition. i.e [How to combine std::copy_if and std::transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400746/how-to-combine-stdcopy-if-and-stdtransform)
- Are worse then the thing I want to replace.

Is this even a good idea?

Comment: What are you doing with the elements of the container that you are storing?  Do you actually need them or are you just saving them to get a sum of them?

Comment: Usually we are saving off an ID for later use.

Comment: OK.  Then the `transform_if` you linked to is probably what you want.

Comment: when stl algorithms are your hammer then almost every problem actually is a nail ;)

Comment: See also: [Why is there no transform_if in the C++ standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579832/why-is-there-no-transform-if-in-the-c-standard-library) and [`boost::transform_if`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/compute/doc/html/boost/compute/transform_if.html)

Comment: With C++20 it will be possible to compose algorithm on ranges element wise (pipe operator of the range library :)).

Comment: It may be possible to create a transforming output iterator to take your input type and extract the output type from it? Then just use `std::copy_if`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quite general solution to your issue would be the following (working example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename It, typename MemberType, typename Cond, typename Do>
void process_filtered(It begin, It end, MemberType iterator_traits<It>::value_type::*ptr, Cond condition, Do process)
{
    for(It it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    {
        if(condition((*it).*ptr))
        {
            process((*it).*ptr);
        }
    }
}

struct Data
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    // thanks to iterator_traits, vector could also be an array;
    // kudos to @Yakk-AdamNevraumont
    vector<Data> lines{{1,2},{4,3},{5,6}};

    // filter even numbers from Data::x and output them
    process_filtered(std::begin(lines), std::end(lines), &Data::x, [](int n){return n % 2 == 0;}, [](int n){cout << n;});

    // output is 4, the only x value that is even

    return 0;
}
```

It does not use STL, that is right, but you merely pass an iterator pair, the member to lookup and two lambdas/functions to it that will first filter and second use the filtered output, respectively.

I like your general solutions but here you do not need to have a lambda that extracts the corresponding attribute.

Clearly, the code can be refined to work with `const_iterator` but for a general idea, I think, it should be helpful. You could also extend it to have a member function that returns a member attribute instead of a direct member attribute pointer, if you'd like to use this method for encapsulated classes.

Comment: `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type` rather than `It::value_type` (`Foo*` has no `::value_type`, but does have a `iterator_traits<Foo*>::value_type`)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont great comment, thank you! I have changed this and also used `std::begin` and `std::end`. Now, in fact, it also works with a plain array

Comment: The function and one of its parameters are both called `foo` – ugh… how about giving the function a meaningful name such as `copy_member_if`?

Comment: @ArneVogel I changed it a bit. This is only proof of concept, though, not production-ready code. Still, thanks for pointing out. `copy_member_if` would be misleading, though, because the function is more general

Answer (score 6):

Sure.  There are a bunch of approaches.

1. Find a library with `transform_if`, like `boost`.
2. Find a library with `transform_range`, which takes a transformation and range or container and returns a range with the value transformed.  Compose this with `copy_if`.
3. Find a library with `filter_range` like the above.  Now, use `std::transform` with your filtered range.
4. Find one with both, and compose filtering and transforming in the appropriate order.  Now your problem is just copying (`std::copy` or whatever).
5. Write your own back-inserter wrapper that transforms while inserting.  Use that with `std::copy_if`.
6. Write your own range adapters, like 2 3 and/or 4.
7. Write `transform_if`.